# Remove Blank Space From Output in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm developing code for monitoring memory that a specific program is using and then, if memory goes too high, it's gonna kill the process.

I'm wondering how I could remove extra blank spaces backward and forward the result, and then put the content into a variable.

Right now, the code is working, but it brings me some blank spaces. I know it's because of the `Format-Table -Hide` function, but I don't know how to fix it.

Eg.: With Chrome process.

```
$Pmemory = Get-Process -Name chrome |
           Group-Object -Property ProcessName |
           Select @{n='Memory';e={'{0:N0}' -f (($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum / 1MB)}} |
           ft -hide |
           Out-String

$Lmemory = 1000
```

After all, I'm gonna compare both values, but my main question is how to remove those blank spaces.

Comment: *"how to remove those blank spaces"* By not having them in the first place. Replace `ft -Hide | Out-String` with `Select-Object -Expand Memory`. Only ever use `Format-*` cmdlet when you're presenting data to a user. NEVER when further processing of the data is intended/required.

Comment: Thank so much. It works!

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the Format-Table and Out-String from your code

Like this

```
$Pmemory = (Get-Process -Name chrome |
           Group-Object -Property ProcessName |
           Select @{n='Memory';e={'{0:N0}' -f (($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum / 1MB)}}).Memory

$Lmemory = 1000
```

Output:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $Pmemory
1.968
```